# Updating react component state after API call. 2022

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a react component that receives one object initially. this object has all the necessary data for me to make an API call and query a DB collection. I have semi acheived what I am needing but it is messy includes some code from outdated tutorials. This  should be easy I would think with react.

**`QuestionComponent.js`**

```js
class QuestionComponent extends React.Component{

    constructState(props){
        var ret = []
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            console.log(props.question.public_token)
            window.API.user_profile(props.question.public_token).then(user => {
                ret['question'] = props.question
                ret['public_token'] = props.question.public_token
                ret['title'] = props.question.title
                ret['author'] = user.username
                console.log(props.question)
                var z = 0
                props.question.tags.forEach(tag => {
                    z++
                    ret['tags'] = [ret['tags'], <TagComponent key={tag+z} text={tag}></TagComponent>] 
                });
                resolve(ret)                 
            })
            
            
        })
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(props)
        this.state = {question:props.question}

        this.constructState(props).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.state = res
        })
        //var isQuestion

        //if(props.isQuestion|| props.isQuestion != undefined){
        //    this.state = {id: props.question.id, title: props.question.title, tags:props.question.tags, author:props.question.author}
        //}else{
        //    console.log('else')
        //    this.state = {id: props.question.id, title: 'test', tags:['test','test'], author:'test author'}
        //}
        

    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('mount')
        this.constructState(this.state.question).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.state = res
        })
    }



    render(){
        return (...)
    }

};

export default QuestionComponent;
```

this is where I am at right now. you can see the `console.log(res)` in the `constructor.construcState()` when i run the code it seems to return Exactly what i want but I think its being evaluated afterwards in the console or I cant set the state properly. I'm still somewhat new to React. could someone show me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about your specific question, but just a general note, I see a lot of things like `this.state = ...` but in React you don't mutate the state directly like that, instead you do `this.setState({whatever : value })`

Comment: Yeah i have tried `this.setState()` in `componentDidMount()` but event that wont work. The component can get all of the data i need returned in the `window.API` promise but i just cant get react to set the components state with the new data

Comment: so your `console.log(res)` in `componentDidMount()` has the data you want, but when you do `this.setState({res:res});` on the next line, the state is not set at all? In that case I'm at a loss. I'm not too good with class based components anymore, I've been using functional components for quite a while now, and the syntax you're using seems even older than what I learned with 2 years ago, so it's too unfamiliar to me to figure out :/

Comment: That is also very useful to know. Is the functional approach better. Reacts class system and entire system in general seems very messy to me.

Comment: Personally I like functional components a lot better now that I've gotten familiar with `useEffect` - I find it so useful that I can't imagine working without it now. I didn't find class-based components all that messy though, in fact I liked how you could set state for multiple properties at once with something like `this.setState({foo:bar,sup:homie,word:holmes});` whereas with functional components you have to do that in three lines, with a different state-setting function for each one. I think it's still just a preference thing, and functional has become my preference